# Why did `failed to build thrift` error appeared after running `pip install` in Windows environment in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does `pip install apache-iotdb` tool not support Windows environment? After running `pip install apache-iotdb==0.13.0.post1` in Windows, an error message appeared: `Failed to build thrift, ERROR: Could not build heels for thrift, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`. I want to know what settings are needed to execute pip-install tool in Apache IoTDB? And how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have python 3.7 or above versions, you should be able to execute `pip install` in Apache IoTDB. For the error you got, the client version of `pip-install` should preferably match the server version of IoTDB. Based on the error message, you can check whether the installation of these two dependencies, `sqlalchemy` and `thrift`, failed due to the version difference.